# Detect ISP (or/and country) by IP Address

Tags: ip

There are plenty of services over the Internet where we can find out the external IP address of our machine, but also such services usually provide information about Internet provider or country (or both).

So my question is: how can I obtain such information programmatically knowing the IP Address? Are there some public catalogs or some API's for retrieving such kind of information?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use my service, the http://ipinfo.io API. Here's an example of the details it provides:

```
$ curl ipinfo.io
{
  "ip": "67.188.232.131",
  "hostname": "c-67-188-232-131.hsd1.ca.comcast.net",
  "city": "Milpitas",
  "region": "California",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "37.44040000000001,-121.87049999999999",
  "org": "AS7922 Comcast Cable Communications, Inc.",
  "postal": "95035",
  "phone": 408
}
```

See http://ipinfo.io/developers for more information.

Comment: Commercial use requires paid plan.

Answer (score 17):

use this `http://ip-api.com/json/[ip address]` example: http://ip-api.com/json/113.14.168.85

output:

```
{"as":"AS4134 Chinanet","city":"Nanning","country":"China","countryCode":"CN","isp":"China Telecom","lat":22.8167,"lon":108.3167,"org":"China Telecom","query":"113.14.168.85","region":"45","regionName":"Guangxi Zhuangzu Zizhiqu","status":"success","timezone":"Asia/Shanghai","zip":""}
```

Comment: Commercial use requires paid plan.

Answer (score 6):

Maxmind's GeoLite Legacy Downloadable Databases contain ASN for IPv4 and IPv6 at:

http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/

Both binary and CSV data formats are available to download for free.  A CSV entry may look like this:

2383101952,2383116287,"AS20001 Time Warner Cable Internet LLC"

The first two fields are IP address range in decimal.  The last field contains the ASN and the entity name.

Alternatively, Internet-Wide Scan Data Repository (which recently launched Censys with free online search and API) includes a regular DNS lookup for all IPv4 PTR records at:

https://scans.io/study/sonar.rdns

The freely downloadable CSV file contains entries such as:

99.99.99.90,adsl-99-99-99-90.dsl.lsan03.sbcglobal.net

The first field is the IP and the second field is the host name which you may be able to use to infer ISP.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the GeoIP database by Maxmind. It's free and I've been using it in many of my java applications.

see http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/

Comment: The free GeoIP databases all lack the ISP informations.

Comment: even some paid versions they are going giving ISP details

Answer (score 1):

Try the [ipdata.co](https://ipdata.co) API. It provides a lot more data on the IP address and is also extremely scalable. i.e. it has 10 global endpoints each of which can handle >800M calls a day!

Example;

```
curl https://api.ipdata.co/70.70.70.70
{
    "ip": "70.70.70.70",
    "city": "",
    "region": "",
    "region_code": "",
    "country_name": "Canada",
    "country_code": "CA",
    "continent_name": "North America",
    "continent_code": "NA",
    "latitude": 43.6319,
    "longitude": -79.3716,
    "asn": "AS6327",
    "organisation": "Shaw Communications Inc.",
    "postal": "",
    "currency": "CAD",
    "currency_symbol": "$",
    "calling_code": "1",
    "flag": "https://ipdata.co/flags/ca.png",
    "emoji_flag": "\ud83c\udde8\ud83c\udde6",
    "time_zone": "",
    "is_eu": false,
    "suspicious_factors": {
        "is_tor": false
    }
}⏎
```

Comment: Commercial use requires paid plan.

Answer (score 0):

Technology is progressing. After reviewing your question 6 years later, [IP2Location](https://www.ip2location.com) is providing country, region or state, city, latitude and longitude, ZIP code, time zone, Internet Service Provider (ISP) or company name, domain name, net speed, area code, weather station code, weather station name, mobile country code (MCC), mobile network code (MNC) and carrier brand, elevation, usage type, proxy detection and types from IP address.

Comment: It requires a paid subscription

Comment: @robertspierre It looks like they offer free API at https://www.ip2location.io